# How to remove special characters, string , number from regax

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

I have. done paramerization in recorded requests in jmeter , when i rerun it some requests. are failing but i have done capture variables and pass to
next requests  but there is issue

format ofresponse is changing dynamically

my regax - `stateToken":"(.+?)"`

```
\x2D is. additionalpart is coming some time so i need re write regax to remove this when we getting that
```

Fail Case

002KljInsq318mkPTkDTuJ06eLSxIQmVga\x2DSuvHmDe

```
{"stateToken":"00UaBoY\x2D81AIL32Nz9qmUJrIarSv3OgfUdd8FHGSkb"}

 
{"stateToken":"003LYZGSYKn3io1ocOwCBNcp2I\x2Dt8UbkdBfruaC6C0"}
 
{"stateToken":"00C8O4pt\x2DcSPEzHrt69zqmEGta9KbjdwywEVdkICku"}
{"stateToken":"00JgMsy7\x2DzXDP0gxaeWv4dj8EguFTWtnLxV\x2DBKTkIq"}
```

Working

```
{"stateToken":"00fswJVHKpW7dNhNVK0bRclBBrsuMLHBBevJ8IS1Wz"}
{"stateToken":"00ZVZXpSJn7v3lxNTrEqy1mAGydgroO5apvoTlWH2u"}
```

any ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

1. It looks like your application has a functional issue, if it returns the token which cannot be used for authentication is sounds like a bug so instead of trying to implement a workaround in JMeter you should report it as it needs to be fixed.
2. [JSON is not a regular language](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/3987/is-json-a-regular-language) hence using regular expressions for extracting data from it is not the best idea, I would recommend considering using [JSON Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor) or [JSON JMESPath Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-jmeter-json-jmespath-extractor-andassertion-a-guide) instead
3. If you still want to bypass the intermittent issue with tokens and remove the problematic element from the token (I repeat I doubt real user of your application will do this) you can do it using a suitable [JSR223 Test Element](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) and the code like:

   ```
   def before = vars.get('token')
   log.info('Before: ' + before)

   def after = before.replace('\\x2D','')
   log.info('After : ' + after)

   vars.put('token', after)
   ```

   Demo:

   [image]

Comment: i tried with  JSR223 Test Element , not working ( i created  JSR223 Test Element for earlier request )